# User provided key in aes encryption c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

AES256 uses 256 bits key which is exactly 32 bytes of data, in terms of ASCII characters its 32 characters. And it is mostly system generated keys.
        I'm developing a project that encrypts a Plain text file using AES Class in C#. In this project there is a window form that asks the user to provide key. Is there a way to encrypt the Plain text using the User Provided key?

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Example of AES256 encryption using System.Security.Cryptography.Aes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400884/c-sharp-example-of-aes256-encryption-using-system-security-cryptography-aes)

Answer (score 2):

You should not ask the user for the *key*. You should ask the user for a *password phrase* and then use one of the industry standards [key derivation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to generate the key from the password phrase, like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). .Net provides support for this with [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class. See the example in the link for how to use it. Also, make sure you generate a good Initialization Vector and prepend it to the encrypted file.

You should never mix system generated keys with user provided password phrases. If you generate keys, then you **must** have a key exchange protocol in place, eg. TLS.

Please spend some time to document yourself about basic crypto. [The Handbook](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) is a good starting read (and free). Don't release Yet Another Broken Crypto product...